# Relative estimation of Bernoulli parameter -- reference request

Tags: statistics, estimation

Suppose I can make i.i.d. samples from the Bernoulli distribution with bias $p$ and want to find approximation $\hat{p} \in [(1-\epsilon)p,(1+\epsilon)p]$ with constant probability. I suppose that this should be possible to do in $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2 p})$ samples. Is this so? If so, are there any papers about this? I have found many papers which looked at maximum likelihood estimates or a Bayesian setting. I am interested in a reference, rather than in a solution as it must exist and I want to reference it in a paper.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to find a reference, though it took me way too long. This paper [1] shows an algorithm that does exactly this, see Theorem 5 in that paper. The idea does not come from this paper, see the references they give.

[1] Sequential sampling techniques for algorithmic learning theory, Osamu Watanabe, https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82665979.pdf